# GUI: action listener compiler-error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors, jbutton

I cannot seem to make the Exit Button work and thus my program does not compile.  If I comment out everything related to the exit button the program works and functions properly.  All other buttons work.  What is wrong with my Exit Button?

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Converterr here.
 * 
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Converterr

{
private JLabel usdL, pesosL, eurosL;
private JTextField usdTF, pesosTF, eurosTF;
private JButton pesosB, eurosB, exitB;
PesosButtonHandler pbHandler;
EurosButtonHandler eubHandler;
ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

    public void driver() 
    {
        JFrame c = new JFrame ("Currency Converter");
        c.setSize(400,300);
        c.setDefaultCloseOperation(c.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Content Pane
        Container cp = c.getContentPane ( );
        cp.setLayout ( new GridLayout (5,2) );


        pesosL = new JLabel ("Pesos: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        usdL = new JLabel ("USD:  ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        eurosL =  new JLabel ("Euros:  ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);


        usdTF = new JTextField(8);
        pesosTF = new JTextField(8);
        eurosTF = new JTextField(8);

        pesosTF.setEditable(false);
        eurosTF.setEditable(false);

        pesosB = new JButton ("Convert to Pesos");
        eurosB = new JButton ("Convert to Euros");
        exitB = new JButton ("Exit");

        // add to content pane container
        cp.add(usdL);
        cp.add(usdTF);

        cp.add(pesosL);
        cp.add(pesosTF);

        cp.add(eurosL);
        cp.add(eurosTF);

        cp.add(pesosB);
        cp.add(eurosB);
        cp.add(exitB);


        c.setVisible(true);

        //Instantiate Listeners
        pbHandler = new PesosButtonHandler();
        eubHandler = new EurosButtonHandler();
      ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

        pesosB.addActionListener(pbHandler);
        eurosB.addActionListener(eubHandler);
       exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);
    }

    //action listener interfaces
    private class PesosButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            double inusd;
            double outpesos;
            inusd = Double.parseDouble(usdTF.getText() );
            outpesos = inusd * 12.31;

            pesosTF.setText(Double.toString(outpesos));    
        }


    }



    private class EurosButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            double inusd, outeuros;
            inusd = Double.parseDouble(usdTF.getText() );
            outeuros = inusd * .78;
            eurosTF.setText(Double.toString(outeuros));
        }   
    }

   private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
   {
       public void ActionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
     {
        System.exit(0);
      }    
  }

public static void main (String [ ] args)
        {
            Converterr conv = new Converterr();
            conv.driver();   
        }
    }
```

### Error Message:

```
Converterr.ExitButtonHandler is not abstract and does not override 
    abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEnvt) in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

Comment: "*my program does not compile"* Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: My apologies:Error Message: Converterr.ExitButtonHandler is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEnvt) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Comment: `ActionEnvt`?  Always **copy/paste** error & exception output. Do it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16683186/edit). Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Where did you get the class `java.awt.event.ActionEnvt`? Shouldn't it be `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`

Answer (score 4):

```
   public void ActionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
```

You have a typo in the method name. It should be:

```
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
```

Comment: That sort of mistake is what `@Override` notation is good for highlighting.